# ElasticSearch terms aggregation by entire field

Tags: ruby, statistics, elasticsearch

How can I write an ElasticSearch term aggregation query that takes into account the entire field value, rather than individual tokens? For example, I would like to aggregate by city name, but the following returns `new`, `york`, `san` and `francisco` as individual buckets, not `new york` and `san francisco` as the buckets as expected.

```
curl -XPOST "http://localhost:9200/cities/_search" -d'
{
   "size": 0, 
   "aggs" : {
     "cities" : {
         "terms" : { 
            "field" : "city",
            "min_doc_count": 10
         }
     }
   }
}'
```

Answer (score 16, accepted):

You should fix this in your mapping. Add a not_analyzed field. You can create the multi field if you also need the analyzed version.

```
"album": {
  "city": "string",
  "fields": {
    "raw": {
      "type": "string",
      "index": "not_analyzed"
    }
  }
}
```

Now create your aggregate on city.raw

Comment: Perfect solution. I don't need the fields analyzed anyway, so I made it a keyword analyzer and it works.

Comment: Anyway to do this without fixing the mapping?

Comment: Not that I know of Henley Chiu

Comment: I tried to go for this solution, but wasnt able to do proper filter queries for the "entire" string

Comment: Hi @PaulH, I am curious why it did not work for you. Maybe create a new question with your problem? This should work for filters, did you use the city.raw field?

Answer (score 6):

**Update at 2018-02-11**
now we can use syntax `.keyword` after grouped by field according to [this](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/_executing_aggregations.html)

```
GET /bank/_search
{
  "size": 0,
  "aggs": {
    "group_by_state": {
      "terms": {
        "field": "state.keyword"
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

[This elastic doc](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/guide/current/aggregations-and-analysis.html) suggests to fix that in mapping (as suggested in the accepted answer) - either to make the field `not_analyzed` or to add a raw field with `not_analyzed` and use it in aggregations.

There is no other way for it. As the aggregations operate upon inverted index and if the field is analyzed, the inverted index is bound to have only tokens and not the original values of the field.